# Import a cls files and create a sheet

Tags: excel, vbide, vba

I went through interesting code examples found at the following URLS 
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

I have adapted the code to export/import modules to my needs still I cannot figure out how I could import a sheet source code file to add it to a new workbook as sheet code. I can easily check for the **VBcomponent** type when I save the component to create a sheet source code file but the **import VBcomponent**  method will wrongly create a new class module after reading the created file no matter what file extension I use. The same problem occurs with **ThisWorkbook** source code file.
The component type and file extension is obtained from this piece of code

```
Public Function VBE_GetFileExtension(VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent) As String
Select Case VBComp.Type
    Case vbext_ct_ClassModule
        VBE_GetFileExtension = ".cls"
    Case vbext_ct_Document
        VBE_GetFileExtension = ".xcls"
    Case vbext_ct_MSForm
        VBE_GetFileExtension = ".frm"
    Case vbext_ct_StdModule
        VBE_GetFileExtension = ".bas"
    Case Else
        VBE_GetFileExtension = ".bas"
End Select
End Function
```

I know it is possible to edit sheet and workbook source code using VBA but I am afraid it won't be very efficient.

Here the full code the export

```
Public Sub VBE_ExportCodeSource()
    If (Not IsEditorInSync()) Then Call SyncVBAEditor

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim sFolderName As String
    sFolderName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ".SrcCodeExport"

    'create folder where to save source code files
    Dim bOk As Boolean
    bOk = Z_bIOCreateFolder(sFolderName)

    'create sub folder where to save modules based on the type
    Dim bOk As Boolean
    bOk = Z_bIOCreateFolder(sFolderName)

    Dim sSubFolderName As String
    sSubFolderName = sFolderName & "\" & "Microsoft Excel Objects"
    bOk = Z_bIOCreateFolder(sSubFolderName)
    If (Not bOk) Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    sSubFolderName = sFolderName & "\" & "Forms"
    bOk = Z_bIOCreateFolder(sSubFolderName)
    If (Not bOk) Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    sSubFolderName = sFolderName & "\" & "Modules"
    bOk = Z_bIOCreateFolder(sSubFolderName)
    If (Not bOk) Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    sSubFolderName = sFolderName & "\" & "Class Modules"
    bOk = Z_bIOCreateFolder(sSubFolderName)
    If (Not bOk) Then GoTo ErrorHandler

    sSubFolderName = sFolderName & "\" & "Active X"
    bOk = Z_bIOCreateFolder(sSubFolderName)
    If (Not bOk) Then GoTo ErrorHandler


    Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
    Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE

    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Set VBProj = VBAEditor.ActiveVBProject

    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
        If (Not VBComp Is Nothing) Then
            bOk = VBE_ExportVBComponent(VBComp, sFolderName)
        End If
    Next VBComp
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox _
        Prompt:="Error while exporting source code", _
        Buttons:=vbExclamation
End Sub

Public Function VBE_ExportVBComponent( _
        ByVal VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent, _
        ByVal sFolderName As String, _
        Optional OverwriteExisting As Boolean = True) As Boolean
'
    VBE_ExportVBComponent = False 'default

    sFolderName = VBE_GetFileSubFolder(sFolderName, VBComp)

    Dim sFileExtension As String
    ' based on module type get the file extension string
    sFileExtension = VBE_GetFileExtension(VBComp:=VBComp)

    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = VBComp.Name & sFileExtension

    ' add path checking for \ at the end of sFolderName
    If StrComp(Right(sFolderName, 1), "\", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        sFileName = sFolderName & sFileName
    Else
        sFileName = sFolderName & "\" & sFileName
    End If

    Dim sFullPathName As String
    sFullPathName = Dir(sFileName, vbNormal + vbHidden + vbSystem)

    'Debug.Print "exporting " & VBComp.Name & " to " & sFileName

    If sFullPathName <> vbNullString Then
        If OverwriteExisting Then
            Kill sFileName
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    VBComp.Export Filename:=sFileName
    VBE_ExportVBComponent = True
End Function
```

Here the full code to import

```
''
' sFolderName  is the full path to a folder which contains subfolders, one for each module type
' sWkbTargetName  is the workbook name created to 'host' the imported modules
Public Sub VBE_ImportModules( _
    ByVal sFolderName As String, _
    ByVal sWkbTargetName As String)
'
    Dim wkbTarget As Excel.Workbook

    Dim bW As Boolean
    bW = (StrComp(sWkbTargetName, ThisWorkbook.Name) <> 0)

    'Get the path to the folder with modules
    Dim bP As Boolean
    bP = Z_bIOExistFolder(sFolderName)

    If (bW And bP) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wkbTarget = Application.Workbooks(sWkbTargetName)
        If (wkbTarget Is Nothing) Then
            Set wkbTarget = Application.Workbooks.Add(sWkbTargetName)
        End If

        If (Not wkbTarget Is Nothing) Then
            If (wkbTarget.VBProject.Protection <> 1) Then
                ''' NOTE: sFolderName where the code modules are located.
                Dim objFSO As Object
                Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


                Dim sSubFolderName As String, asSubFolderName(1 To 5) As String
                asSubFolderName(1) = sFolderName & "\" & "Microsoft Excel Objects" & "\"
                asSubFolderName(2) = sFolderName & "\" & "Forms" & "\"
                asSubFolderName(3) = sFolderName & "\" & "Modules" & "\"
                asSubFolderName(4) = sFolderName & "\" & "Class Modules" & "\"
                asSubFolderName(5) = sFolderName & "\" & "Active X" & "\"
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = LBound(asSubFolderName) To UBound(asSubFolderName)
                    sSubFolderName = asSubFolderName(i)
                    If (objFSO.GetFolder(sSubFolderName).Files.Count > 0) Then

                        'Here we should/could Delete all modules in the target workbook

                        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponents
                        Set VBComp = wkbTarget.VBProject.VBComponents

                        ''' Import all the code modules in the specified path
                        ''' to the ActiveWorkbook.
                        Dim objFile As Object
                        'objFile = CreateObject("Scripting.File")
                        For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(sSubFolderName).Files

                            If (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "cls") Or _
                                (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "xcls") Or _
                                (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "frm") Or _
                                (objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "bas") _
                            Then
                                'Debug.Print "Importing a new component from : " & objFile.Path
                                VBComp.Import objFile.Path
                            End If

                        Next objFile
                        Debug.Print "Files from '" & sSubFolderName & "' imported"
                    Else
                        Debug.Print _
                            "There are no files to import, " & _
                            "in import Folder '" & sSubFolderName & "'"
                    End If
                Next i
            Else
                Debug.Print _
                    "The VBA in this workbook is protected, " & _
                    "not possible to Import the code"
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Cannot open workbook '" & sWkbTargetName & "'"
        End If
    Else
        If (Not bW) Then _
            Debug.Print _
                "Select another target workbook, " & _
                "Not possible to import code in this workbook "
        If (Not bP) Then _
            Debug.Print "Import Folder '" & sFolderName & "' does not exist"
    End If
End Sub

Public Function VBE_GetFileExtension(VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent) As String
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' This returns the appropriate file extension based on the Type of
    ' the VBComponent.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Select Case VBComp.Type
        Case vbext_ct_ClassModule
            VBE_GetFileExtension = ".cls"
        Case vbext_ct_Document
            VBE_GetFileExtension = ".xcls"
        Case vbext_ct_MSForm
            VBE_GetFileExtension = ".frm"
        Case vbext_ct_StdModule
            VBE_GetFileExtension = ".bas"
        Case Else
            VBE_GetFileExtension = ".bas"
    End Select
End Function
```

some code to deal with folders

```
''
' Z_bIOCreateFolder
Private Function Z_bIOCreateFolder(ByVal sFolderPath As String) As Boolean
    Z_bIOCreateFolder = False ' default
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not Z_bIOExistFolder(sFolderPath) Then
        On Error GoTo IOCreateFolderErrorTrap
        objFSO.CreateFolder sFolderPath ' could there be any error with this, like if the path is really screwed up?
        Z_bIOCreateFolder = True
    End If
Exit Function
IOCreateFolderErrorTrap:
    Call MsgBox("A folder could not be created for the following path: " & sFolderPath & ". Check the path name and try again.")
End Function
''
' Z_bIOExistFolder
Private Function Z_bIOExistFolder(ByVal sFolderPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        On Error GoTo IOExistFolderErrorTrap
    Z_bIOExistFolder = objFSO.FolderExists(sFolderPath)
Exit Function
IOExistFolderErrorTrap:
    Call MsgBox("objFSO failed checking: " & sFolderPath)
End Function
```

The result as displayed in the image below (Feuil* are created from sheet code).

[image]

Comment: *the import VBcomponent method will wrongly create a new class module after reading the created file not matter what file extension I use* - where is your code to import the module. i do not believe your statement is true.

Comment: @scott please see the extended post where I added the full code

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code you have already and add some extra code to transfer the sheet code into your sheets or workbook!

1. since the **`*.cls` files for your sheet/workbook code** (in your case `Feuil*.cls`) **cannot be differentiated from class modules** by name or content, **you have to have some way to differentiate them manually**

   - **e.g.** exporting them into **special subfolders `.../workbooks/`, `.../worksheets/`**
2. before you import a specific `*.cls` file you **create the according sheet first** (with `Worksheets.Add ...`) and name it correctly (with `myWorksheet.Name = ...`)

   - e.g. `Feuil1.cls` => `Feuil1` sheet
3. **import** it the way you did and let it be created **as a class module** (where they will be named with an additional **`1` suffixed** because of the name conflict

   - e.g. `Feuil1.cls` => `Feuil11` class module
4. **copy the code itself from the class module to the sheet/workbook code**

   - e.g. based on the reflection code under [*CopyModule(...)*](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)  (or similar code on the page)
   - based on:

     ```
     With VBComp.CodeModule
         .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
         S = TempVBComp.CodeModule.Lines(1, TempVBComp.CodeModule.CountOfLines)
         .InsertLines 1, S
     End With
     ```
5. **delete the temporary imported class module**

   - e.g. `Feuil11`