# Excel 2016 office 365 catastrophic failure

Tags: excel, vba

Start to get Excel catastrophic failure error

[image]

On OK opening debug windows, with auto creating each time new sheets, which is empty and strange structure

[image]

[image]

If I want something to do appears

[image]

So how to delete those sheets? or fix that error?
No background process started, file stored in xlsm and xlsb format do the same things. workbook and worksheets is not protected.

[image]

Comment: It looks like some loop gone wrong creating all those extra sheets? (i.e.: Sheet11, Sheet111, Sheet1111, etc, etc). I think you still have the code running, hence the greyed out `remove` option... But you should check the code and try to step through maybe?

Comment: I delete all code and problem the same

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code it is hard to give debugging advice. Please provide a [mcve] rather than context-free screenshots of debugging data.

Comment: no debugging data, it is empty

Comment: Perhaps you have a virus? We have literally nothing to go on. Simply deleting sheets won't help if some unknown process is constantly creating them. Maybe your Excel installation has become somehow corrupt.  If so, a reinstall might help. Are you sure that you don't have something like an Add-in which is running?

Comment: can you explain what the file does when opened? Do you have some code associated  to workbook or sheets open events ?

Comment: *I delete all code and problem the same* Did you try also deleting code of your personal macro workbooks?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the file has been corrupted. It is unlikelly the problem can be easily reproduced from scratch.
Never the less you can script a vba macro to delete Sheets based on their names or not delete the sheets you want to keep.

```
sheetnametodelete= "sheetname"
With Application.Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name())
        .Unprotect (yourpassword)  ' required if protection is set
            Dim wks As Worksheet
            Set wks = .Sheets(sheetnametodelete)
            If (Not wks Is Nothing) Then ' also check if wks belong to the defined blacklist
                wks.Delete
            End If
        .Protect (yourpassword) ' required if protection is set
End With
```

Try to open the file from another computer in case your local Excel config is corrupted.

I had a similar problem (a fake workbook duplicated) in the past and decided to script a build process for my Excel vba based application.

See following links to learn more about module management.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win002.htm

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

you can also look at this post 
[Import a cls files and create a sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029134/import-a-cls-files-and-create-a-sheet)

It provides code and comments from other contributors.
This is obviously not direct answer to your problem but if you intend to work on a consistent vba project I recommand to save your vba code out of your Excel file once in a while and setup a build of your Excel app.

Comment: Good advice (+1) but OP's statement that "file stored in xlsm and xlsb format do the same things" suggests that maybe the problem does not lie with a single file. On the other hand, maybe they just mean that if they re-save this one file using a different extension then the problem remains.